# Need a little guidance with PivotTable

Tags: excel, vba

I run the same reports every day and would like to use a generic VBA code that selects all my data  and creates the pivot table. I've recorded the MACRO:

- I need the data range selected automatically to be allow any data amount
- I need the data range to be selected automatically
- The sheet should not matter
- Finally I would like to name the sheet

code:

```
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable26").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet4!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable27" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable27").PivotFields("Date Opened")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable27").PivotFields("Date Opened")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable27").PivotFields("Queue")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable27").PivotFields("Sub Queue")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable27").PivotFields("Status")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable27").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable27").PivotFields("Source"), "Count of Source", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable27").PivotFields("Queue")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Post what you have done so far.

Comment: My suggestion is to use a better title. We all need a little guidance. Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little code to get you what you asked in your post:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoPivot()

Dim PT              As PivotTable
Dim PTCache         As PivotCache
Dim PtDataRng       As Range
Dim ws              As Worksheet
Dim LastRow         As Long
Dim LastCol         As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("PivotData") ' <-- modify "PivotData" to your sheet's name that holds the dynamic data
With ws
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' <-- get last column with data in row 1
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlToLeft).Row ' <-- get last row with data in column A
    Set PtDataRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)) ' <-- set the dynamic Range
End With

' create a new wroksheet, place it at the end, and use an InputBox to select it's name
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = Application.InputBox("Select A Valid Name for new sheet", Type:=2)

' set the Pivot Cache to updated dynamic Ranget
Set PTCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PtDataRng)

' Create Pivot Table from Pivot Cache
Set PT = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:=ws.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTableTest")

' set the fields setting in the Pivot Table
With PT
    With .PivotFields("Date Opened")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Date Opened")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Queue")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Sub Queue")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Status")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    .AddDataField .PivotFields("Source"), "Count of Source", xlCount
    With .PivotFields("Queue")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With

End With

End Sub
```